# d3 chart - get x axis time of max value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a array of values `[date, value]`.

I can find the max value with:

```
max_value = d3.max(data_array, function(d) { return d[1]; } );
```

How do I get the `d[0]` value of `d[1]` maximum so I can mark the position of maximum value on chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript array `filter` function.

```
var  max_value = d3.max(data_array, function(d) { return d[1]; } );
var requiredArr = data_array.filter(function(d){     
   return d[1]==max_value; 
});
var dateWithMaxValue = requiredArr[0];
```

Comment: Why do you recompute the `max_value` in every `filter` iteration step? And what is `requiredObject`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about performance too much, here's a one-liner:

```
// d is [x, y] where x is what you're looking for
var d = data_array.sort(function (a, b) { return b[1] - a[1]; })[0];
```

Here's a simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4eahv69s/).